# How to make a particular label blink in JList 

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist, renderer

I've managed to use panel as a cell render component for `JList`. And the blink label contained in the panel works OK in its own right. but after I whacked render onto the list, the label stopped blinking.

I worked around by refreshing list at certain interval to be able to see the blink, however this time all the labels in the list start blinking (I only wanted certain labels met condition in the list blink). I've delved into it hours try to work it out but chance looks dim.

My question lies in 2 layers:

1. Why the self-contained blink-label-prove panel need `JList` to refresh to view the blink?
2. Why the particular label not singled out during rendering causing all the label in the list singing and dancing?

Comment: You know of course that the renderer acts as a rubber stamp showing images of a JLabel, but really isn't *the* JLabel, and often this is the source of problems. That being said, it's hard to say exactly what you're doing wrong without code. Consider creating a small compilable runnable program that we can run, test and modify and that demonstrates your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The mentioned label is a child component in that rendering panel cell. So if the individual case was working (i.e the label will blink if met certain condition), why it would need list to refresh to see the effect since all of these should be overhauled during rendering (getListCellRendererComponent). This part of codesnipt something look like that:

Comment: please see my code posted as an answer to see a sample SSCCE, and also a way of blinking a label in a JList.

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your last comment though. Please clarify.

Comment: your code is hunkydory. Haven't fully tapped into my context, but it looks sound. The only difference is I have numerous label in a rendering panel, only one of them need blink if need. I made my render extends jpanel and didn't make a sep component from overriden methods. Would that matter??

Comment: I'm not sure. I think I would need to see your code to better understand it.

Answer (score 4):

This [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) works for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlinkingLabelInList extends JPanel {
   public static final Color FLASH_COLOR = Color.red;
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 500;
   private String[] data = {"Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri"};
   private JList list = new JList(data);
   public Color cellColor = null;


   public BlinkingLabelInList() {
      add(new JScrollPane(list));
      list.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         cellColor = (cellColor == null) ? FLASH_COLOR : null;
         list.repaint();
      }
   }

   private class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
      @Override
      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
         Component cellRenderer = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
               cellHasFocus);
         if (isSelected || cellHasFocus) {
            cellRenderer.setForeground(cellColor );
         } else {
            cellRenderer.setForeground(null);
         }
         return cellRenderer;
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BlinkingLabelInList mainPanel = new BlinkingLabelInList();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlinkingLabelInList");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```